# What do "spatial" and "temporal" mean in the context of image processing?

Tags: computer-vision, terminology, image-processing

I am new to image processing. I am trying to understand CNNs from [this blog post](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-convolutional-neural-networks-the-eli5-way-3bd2b1164a53). Here's an excerpt from that article that mentions these terms.

> A ConvNet is able to successfully capture the Spatial and Temporal dependencies in an image through the application of relevant filters. The architecture performs a better fitting to the image dataset due to the reduction in the number of parameters involved and reusability of weights.

I am not able to understand the terms **spatial** and **temporal**, and their respective dependencies in images. I have encountered the spatial and temporal many times. However, still, I am not able to understand how space (spatial) and temporal(time) concepts map to an image.

(By the way, in the quote above, what does the term "reusability of weights" mean?)